# Gitea LFS mirroring is failing due to x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

Tags: docker, https, ssl-certificate, git-lfs, gitea

We are using two Gitea servers version 1.16.9. The second Gitea functions as a mirror for the first instance. The mirrors are set up with the HTTPS protocol. The initial sync is done successful, but any ongoing sync fails with a Unknown authority for the LFS sync.

```
2023/11/09 10:40:00 ...irror/mirror_pull.go:286:runSync() [E] SyncMirrors [repo: 76:Novum/DevEnv]: failed to synchronize LFS objects for repository: Post "https://xxx:***@yyyy.zzzz/MyProject.git/info/lfs/objects/batch": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

The official docker image is used and we have deployed the certificates and the authority in the mounted volume : gitea/giteadata/gitea/conf/cert

I know I could disable git sslVerify, which I do not accept as a valid answer.

How to get LFS sync working?

Changed certificates used in both instances.
Did not try to use ssh keys and I currently don't want to go down this path.
I know I could disable git sslVerify, which I do not accept as a valid answer.

Comment: Are you using a valid certificate issued by a public CA?  Note that you can issue Let's Encrypt certificates for internal domains using DNS, so there's no reason you shouldn't do so.

Comment: We are not using certificates issued by a public CA, but generate them ourself with our domain (Microsoft Active Directory Certificate Services) and I am sure it's valid since it works for server access etc. Our CA certificate is populated through our systems PC, servers, phones.

For some reason git clone works also with lfs files, but then any sync after that only syncs commits without lfs file storage. It seems LFS is working differently than GIT regarding the certificates.